# How to use t letter in DateTime format in .Net?

Tags: .net, datetime, datetime-format

I have tried to use

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddtHH:mm");
```

to get a string like "2011-12-02t12:39" (which is a lowercase version of ISO 8601 standard format).

but got "2011-12-02A12:39" instead where "A" means "AM". As both the experiment and the documentation say 't' changes into 'A' for AM and 'P' for "PM".

But I need just a bare 't' the letter in any case. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use apostrophes to have literal content in the format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd't'HH:mm");
```

Comment: Cool. Exactly the way it is in Scala.

Comment: @Ivan Can also be written like `.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd\tHH:mm")` (assuming C# where `@` can be used to ensure that the string literal won't contain a `TAB` (tabulator character `'\t'`) but a backslash followed by a `t`).